# adding google ads to a webpage : access denied

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, adsense

I am trying to add google adsence adds to my website. I created a adunit and copied the code to my webpage. when I'm trying to run that page in browser(IE) I am getting following exception

> "0x80070005 - JavaScript runtime error: Access is denied."

```
        <!-- Homepage -->
        <ins class="adsbygoogle"
             style="display:inline-block;width:300px;height:600px"
             data-ad-client="ca-pub-3585435689000xx"
             data-ad-slot="151456789"></ins>
        <script>
            (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
        </script>
```

Comment: Do you open your page with the integrated web browser in visual studio?